# Deferred versus promise

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, promise

What is the difference between Deferred and Promise other than the jQuery versions?

What should I use for my need?  I only want to call the `fooExecute()`.  I only need the `fooStart()` and `fooEnd()` to toggle the html div status for example.

```
//I'm using jQuery v2.0.0
function fooStart() { /* Start Notification */ }
function fooEnd() { /* End Notification */ }
function fooExecute() { /* Execute the scripts */ }

$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    var deferred1 = $.Deferred();
    var promise1 = $.Promise();

    deferred1.???

    promise1.???
});
```

Comment: [Possible help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384564/using-jquery-deferred-and-promise)

Comment: You cannot change the state of the promise. Thus, it is handled to the requesting logic (which might have no business in tampering with the conditions logic - to resolve or to reject) - to wait for the resolution - from the factory logic that actually created that deferred. Deferred can be `resolve`d or `reject`ed changing its state, which its Promise will also reflect.

Tell me how do you want to use deferreds for clicks?

Comment: I don't think your example could benefit from promises (or I don't understand it). Maybe have a look at [How can jQuery deferred be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869609/how-can-jquery-deferred-be-used?rq=1).

Answer (score 144, accepted):

First: You cannot use `$.Promise();` because it does not exist.

A **deferred object** is an object that can *create* a promise and change its state to `resolved` or `rejected`. Deferreds are typically used if you write your own function and want to provide a promise to the calling code. You are the **producer** of the value.

A **promise** is, as the name says, a promise about future value. You can attach callbacks to it to get that value. The promise was "given" to you and you are the **receiver** of the future value.
You cannot modify the state of the promise. Only the code that *created* the promise can change its state.

#### Examples:

1. (**produce**) You use deferred objects when you want to provide promise-support for your own functions. You compute a value and want to control when the promise is resolved.

```
function callMe() {
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        d.resolve('some_value_compute_asynchronously');
    }, 1000);
    return d.promise();
}

callMe().done(function(value) {
    alert(value);
});
```

2. (**forward**) If you are calling a function which itself returns a promise, then you don't have to create your own deferred object. You can just return that promise. In this case, the function does not create value, but forwards it (kind of):

```
function fetchData() {
    // do some configuration here and pass to `$.ajax`
    return $.ajax({...});
}

fetchData().done(function(response) {
    // ...
});
```

3. (**receive**) Sometimes you don't want to create or pass along promises/values, you want to use them directly, i.e. you are the receiver of some information:

```
$('#my_element').fadeOut().promise().done(function() {
    // called when animation is finished
});
```

Of course, all these use cases can be mixed as well. Your function can be the receiver of value (from an Ajax call for example) and compute (produce) a different value based on that.

---

Related questions:

- [What are the differences between Deferred, Promise and Future in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6801283/218196)
- [What's the difference between a Deferred object and its own promise object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8073528/218196)

Answer (score 2):

A promise is something you can set on a deferred object that executes when the deferred collection is complete.

Example from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/promise/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
div {
  height: 50px; width: 50px;
  float: left; margin-right: 10px;
  display: none; background-color: #090;
}
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Go</button>
<p>Ready...</p>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>


<script>
$("button").on( "click", function() {
  $("p").append( "Started...");

  $("div").each(function( i ) {
    $( this ).fadeIn().fadeOut( 1000 * (i+1) );
  });

  $( "div" ).promise().done(function() {
    $( "p" ).append( " Finished! " );
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here it is in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CUWRD/)

This runs a function on each `div` and executes the `.promise` code when all `.each` executions are complete.