# How to call deferred functions sequentially?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

My code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['m'])) {
    $m = $_GET['m'];
    sleep($m);
    print "done, m=$m";
    die;
}
?>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>

    function w(s) {
        document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML+ "<br>" + s
    }

    function aaa(def) {
        w("begin aaa");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                m: 5
            }
        }).done(function(html) {
            w(html);
            def.resolve();
        });
    }


    function bbb(def) {
        w("begin bbb");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                m: 1
            }
        }).done(function(html) {
            w(html);
            def.resolve();
        });
    }

    $(function() {

        $.when(
            $.Deferred(function(d) { aaa(d) }).promise(),
            $.Deferred(function(d) { bbb(d) }).promise()
        ).done(function() {
            w("OK")
        });
    })
</script>
```

I'm expecting the second function to wait for the first one to complete, that is, my output should be

```
begin aaa
   <--pause
done, m=1
begin bbb
   <--pause
done, m=5
OK
```

Instead I'm getting

```
begin aaa
begin bbb
   <--pause
done, m=1
   <--pause
done, m=5
OK
```

I guess I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about how deferreds work - can anyone shed a light?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How do you expect them to be executed in order if there is no dependency between them? `$.when` doesn't have and cannot have an influence on the evaluation of the promise, it just waits until each of the promises is resolved.

Your code is way more complicated then it needs to be. `$.ajax` already returns a promise which gets resolved when the Ajax response was received, so you can just return it from the functions. If you want to execute them in sequence, you can chain them via [`.then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

> These filter functions can return a new value to be passed along to the promise's `.done()` or `.fail()` callbacks, or they can return another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will pass its resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's callbacks.

So your code simplifies to:

```
function aaa() {
    w("begin aaa");
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            m: 5
        }
    }).done(w);
}


function bbb() {
    w("begin bbb");
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            m: 1
        }
    }).done(w);
}

aaa().then(bbb).done(function() { w('ok'); });
```

Here, `aaa().then(bbb)` creates the dependency you need. It basically means "once `aaa`'s promise is resolved, execute `bbb`". In addition, `.then` returns a new promise, which gets resolved when the promise returned by `bbb` gets resolved, which allows you to execute a function when the promises of both, `aaa` and `bbb` are resolved.

Maybe these help you to understand promises (and deferreds) better:

- [Deferred versus promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17308172/218196)
- http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/

---

Example without `$.ajax`:

```
function aaa() {
    var def = new $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        def.resolve(21);
    }, 3000);
    return def.promise();
}

function bbb(v) {
    var def = new $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        def.resolve(v * 2);
    }, 1000);
    return def.promise();
}

// aaa -> bbb -> console.log
// The value is logged after 3 + 1 seconds
aaa().then(bbb).done(function(v) { console.log(v); }); // 42

// (aaa | bbb) -> console.log
// The value is logged after max(3, 1) seconds and both resolved values are
// passed to the final promise
$.when(aaa(), bbb(5)).done(function(v) { console.log(v); }); // [21, 10]
```

Comment: So, if you want to chain, `A -> B -> C`, use `.then`. If you want to run them in parallel and do something when they are all finished, `(A | B) -> C`, use `$.when` :) And your're welcome!

Comment: For my better understanding, could you add an example with something instead of `$.ajax` that isn't a deferred per se, like e.g. `setTimeout`.

Comment: Added the example. I think (hope) that my explanation of deferreds and promises in http://stackoverflow.com/q/17308172/218196 is good.

Comment: Thanks again, I think I got it. I wish there would be a "wait here" semicolon in JS, as in `loadAjaxStuff() ;; showResult()`. (I guess this is what Monads do, but I can't wrap my head around them either).

Comment: Uh, I never got into Monads either. I don't know, I like how JavaScript works in the browser. Everything is basically event based, and the concept of promises makes composition relatively easy. This is a great article about callbacks vs promises, which also explains the concept of promises in more detail and compares  them to monads as well: https://blog.jcoglan.com/2013/03/30/callbacks-are-imperative-promises-are-functional-nodes-biggest-missed-opportunity/. I can say it changed a bit how I think about promises. The follow up article is not bad either: http://preview.tinyurl.com/nr6fkst

Answer (score 1):

`$.when()` doesn't impose any order on its arguments - they are effectively an "unordered list".

However, `.done()`, `.fail()` and `.then()` do impose order.

First, simplify things by amending `aaa()` and `bbb()` to return the Promise-compatible object returned by the `$.ajax().done()` chain, as follows :

```
function aaa() {
    w("begin aaa");
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: { m: 5 }
    }).done(w);//without changing anything, w can be passed rather than called from an anonymous function.
}

function bbb() {
    w("begin bbb");
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: { m: 1 }
    }).done(w);//without changing anything, w can be passed rather than called from an anonymous function.
}
```

Now, to get the effect you seek, use `.then()` to sequence `aaa` and `bbb` :

```
$(function() {
    aaa().then(bbb).done(function() {
        w("OK");
    });
});
```

I agree it's slightly confusing here that `aaa` is executed and `bbb` is passed, but this is a very common pattern that you will encounter again and again. Eventually it will make sense.

To put `aaa` and `bbb` on par with each other, you could write something like :

```
$(function() {
    $.Deferred().resolve().then(aaa).then(bbb).done(function() {
        w("OK");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I hope yours and Felix's answers make this a good reference topic.